# Django init stuff at base.html from database

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am looking for better solution then my one. I have base.html which represents my layout, at the top of the layout is menu. The trick is that some menu items are 'generated' depending on database values. I have dynamic application where user can log in, the menu item is 'projects' and I want there only projects for specific user. Another user can have different projects, so different menu items are generated for him.
I had one idea, but I'm not very satisfied with this, and it is making ajax calls and set html of this menu element. There is a problem that ajax calls would ask server for data after every request. Do you have an idea how to sensibly solve my problem? thanks.
I forgot to specify I am using Django framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have some kind of [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/) mechanism, you are going to have to make a database query in order to populate `projects` list for current user every time a request is made, regardless of whether you use AJAX or not.

The question here should be doing this as generic as possible so that each template will have that `projects` array present without changing all of the view functions in the backend. Personally, I would recommend you to create a `context processor` if you'll be displaying projects menu in every template.

> The **context_processors** option is a list of callables – called context processors – that take a request object as their argument and return a dictionary of items to be merged into the context.

Create a file named `context_processors.py` in your project root path right next to settings.py:

**context_processors.py**

```
define projects(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        return {}
    else:
        return {'projects': request.user.project_set.all()}
```

and add this into [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) list defined in **settings.py**:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'myproject.context_processors.projects',
)
```

In your so called **base.html** template, 'projects' variable will be present as long as current user is logged in:

**base.html**

```
{% block menu %}
  {% for project in projects %}
    Do whatever you want to do with {{project}}
  {% empty %}
    Either user is not logged in or they don't have a project.
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, this seems to be ideal solution, but I only have one question. How does it determine if it needs to call the function in  context_processors.py? For example I am not logged in and I'm browsing the page, then I log in and it calls the function, or it is calling it every request?

Comment: Any function added in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` list is called  in every request.